# Refactoring code - general way to handle it

Tags: javascript, algorithm, language-agnostic, refactoring

I have a code which has a `start()` function that executes every cycle. In it I call a `pause()` function here and there.

I now have to become more smart of the way I call the `pause()` depending on some conditions. And in some places it is executed on conditions that are not needed in other places.

I understand that I now have to create a separate function which will call the `pause()` function. But that is as far as i have gotten. It feels like a maze and I'm getting lost.

What is the best way to code this? How do the pros do it?

**Update:**

I've added my code. Basically I want my `pauseActivator` to do more than one action.

1. Act as condition tester and return true or false.
2. To actually call the pause function.

Maybe I shouldn't make my function do this?

```
void doPause() {
   //call system default pause function()
}

bool pauseOn = true;
string myPauseTime = "02:30";
bool pauseTimeReached = false;

bool pauseActivator() {
    if(pauseOn && systemTime() == myPauseTime){
        pauseTimeReached = true;
        doPause();
    } 
    return (pauseTimeReached);  
}

int start() {
    if(maxMovement > 500 && pauseActivator()) {
        if(maxA() && secondMovement==600) {
            pauseActivator();
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: C++, Java and JavaScript are very different languages. I sincerely doubt you're using all three of them.

Comment: Use an IDE (Refactor: *extract method*)

Comment: my question is not programming language dependant. it is a very general

Comment: Ok i've added my code after the "update"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use DoPause for pausing and have a function to return the pause state.  Having a test function with a "hidden" side-effect of actually pausing could cause problems down the line.

Comment: I understand that functions should only perform one task. But, I wanted to bundle the two actions, so programatically my code in centralized into one function.